# How to remove unversioned file permanently from git

Tags: git

I have a repo where I kept my source code. I have cloned and built and run, and I am trying to remove file which is unversioned but unable to delete. I have tried with the below command

```
git clean -n -d 
git clean -f -d
git clean -f -d -x
git clean -x -i
```

see below image

[image]

It's not deleting when I try to delete manually, but after building the project again it's showing in git local change. Please help show me how to permanently delete the unversioned or local untracked file, so that after building the project it should not show in local change. I want to see only the local change file which is related to the project.

Comment: ignore them and it was..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to physically delete those files, because anyway they will be created during the build. Instead, you need to add those files to `.gitignore` file - either by name, or by file extension. As an example, more details [could be found here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore).